Изменение вебхука
Подскажите пожалуйста как изменить уже отправленный вебхук

нужно чтобы вместо надписи никого добавился тег, а также если уже был тег должен добавиться новый
То есть человек отправляет команду
/дежурство Pillbox начать

и его тег добавляется в список
и если человек отправляет команду
/дежурство Pillbox закончить

то тег удаляется

Никак. Отправленное сообщение с помощью вебхука нельзя изменить.
Одним из вариантов будет лишь удаление сообщения с вебхуком, предварительно сохранив данные о нём и отправка его заново с новыми данными.

спасибо, я уже узнал на другом форуме как изменить
